# What is the maximum speed of the Cessna Citation X?

Tags: aircraft-design, faa-regulations, aerodynamics, air-traffic-control

What is the maximum speed of the Cessna Citation X?

I want to attempt to break the sound barrier but I do not know if its possible, where, or how to do it.

Comment: If you want to break the sound barrier, there are a number of places you can go to buy rides in ex-military aircraft more than capable of doing it without breaking apart. Would be much cheaper than buying a Citation X and having the insurance company deny the claim (not that you'd be there to contest it anyway).

Comment: A better candidate for what you're asking about might be the G650. Published MMO is 0.925, with rumors of flight tests beyond 1.0 that were no big deal. May be problematc to get somebody to just lend you one for a joyride, though. I've heard the Russians will sell you a MiG-25 ride for the right price, so that may be your best bet.

Comment: If you just want to break the sound barrier then an ex-military jet of some kind is probably the simplest way. If you have EUR 11,500 then [these guys](http://www.flyfighterjet.com/fly-mig-29-russia-sokol-nizhniy-novgorod-moscow) will take you in a MiG-29, for example. And as a general comment, I suggest that before posting questions you consider exactly what you want to know, e.g. do you want to know the maximum airspeed of a Citation X, or do you want to know where/how you can break the sound barrier? Those are completely different questions.

Comment: @TomMcW eh, I'd find a better example, those damages were due to the excessive g-loads.

Comment: If you want to do it, become a test pilot and then you will be allowed to fly the Citation X a bit above MMO. The safety margin until flutter or Mach tuck will kill you should allow to go supersonic. But once you are a test pilot I am sure you will see the silliness of that particular concept.

Comment: @PascalAckermann To my knowledge Cessna no longer lists specifications for the out-of-production Citation X, only for the Citation X+. Are you sure you were looking at information for the Citation X (S/Ns up through 75-0500)? Don't mistake the Citation X+ speed specifications listed on Wikipedia and Cessna's website for the Citation X. They are different. See the [TCDS](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/0/7C49B3121E0C47B886257EA40054AB1B?OpenDocument). And tell me a novice should be able to interpret a TCDS.

Comment: No, they still sell it.  I am a pilot and I see them in airports.  I also fly them.

Comment: @DanielChung Oh, fly the Citation X, do you? Cessna may still sell the Citation X, but all new production has moved to the Citation X+.

Answer (score 8):

**The Cessna Citation X has a maximum speed limitation of 0.92 Mach.**

The following limitations apply to the Cessna Citation X, serial numbers 750-0001 through 750-0500:

- Below 8000 ft., the maximum operating speed (Vmo) is 270 KIAS.
- Between 8000 ft. and 30650 ft., the maximum operating speed (Vmo) is 350 KIAS.
- Above 30650 ft., the maximum operating speed (Mmo) is 0.92 Mach.

---

**The Cessna Citation X+ has a maximum speed limitation of 0.935 Mach.**

The following limitations apply to the Cessna Citation X+, serial numbers 750-0501 and on:

- Below 8000 ft., the maximum operating speed (Vmo) is 270 KIAS.
- Between 8000 ft. and 31500 ft., the maximum operating speed (Vmo) is 350 KIAS.
- Above 31500 ft., the maximum operating speed (Mmo) is 0.92 Mach.

---

All information above is cited from the Cessna Model 750 type certificate number [T00007WI](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/0/7C49B3121E0C47B886257EA40054AB1B?OpenDocument).

---

While the Citation X+ is currently the fastest production civil aircraft, its top speed at altitude is still a little below the the speed of sound. At lower altitudes, the speed limitations are even more restrictive, keeping the aircraft well below the local speed of sound.

The speed of sound is expressed as Mach 1.0. The Citation X is limited to Mach 0.92 and the Citation X+ is limited to Mach 0.935. This means that neither of the Citation X series aircraft are allowed to be flown at or beyond the speed of sound.

**The limitations for the Citation X series of aircraft prohibit flight at or above the speed of sound, Mach 1.0. Attempts to do so are generally against regulation, reckless, and ill advised.**

Answer (score 5):

The Citation X maximum speed is Mach 0.935.

You could have gleaned this information from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_Citation_X#Specifications_.28Citation_X.29), which you are obviously familiar with from your other questions.

What this has to do with breaking the sound barrier is entirely unclear. The Citation X is **not** the aircraft to do it with, but if you have funds I'm sure you could find a privately owned warbird that is designed for it and a pilot/owner who'll oblige you.

Comment: Wikipedia has an incorrect figure. The Mmo of Citation X is 0.92 M. The 0.935  figure is for Citation X+

Answer (score 0):

From [Cessna Citation X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_Citation_X):

> - **Maximum speed**: Mach .935 (MMO)

So, no. Exceeding the maximum rated speed in that aircraft would be highly inadvisable. More generally, so would attempting to exceed the sound barrier in *any* aircraft that is not specifically designed to do so.

Comment: Would the plane shake or something and could I do at sea level where the sound barrier is lower?

Comment: @DanielChung I don't know exactly what you mean by the sound barrier being lower at sea level, but note that the speed of sound is higher in denser materials and slower in less dense material. In other words the speed of sound is higher at sea level and lower at 30,000 ft.

Comment: @DanielChung The maximum speed is expressed in the **local speed of sound** (Mach number), not relative to the speed of sound at sea level. The aircraft is physically limited due to supersonic effects, not to a certain true air speed.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in many of the previous answers, The Cessna Citation X (Mach 0.92) and X+ (Mach 0.935) are fast, but not fast enough to go rattling windows at altitude.

Breaking the sound barrier sans concord service can still be done and I’ve seen quite a few answers here that I believe are correct, but a bit expensive.

Assuming you aren’t in the top 1%, there might be another option to at least get you in a jet that’s fully capable of Mach 1+, and the best part is the price: $0.00.

The United States Airforce has an image to maintain and it loves to create as many cheerleaders as possible with different outreach programs, air shows, the Blue Angeles flying over the Super Bowl, etc…

There are two additional ways I’m aware of that might have you joining the supersonic club:

1. A pilot can request that you be permitted to go up with him on a flight. I don’t know if these are granted or requested often. It’s the kind of thing people sometimes get to do as a reward for something like saving a Airforce Generals kid from a burning building or catching a terrorist. Also, If some reporter is on the scene and asks if you’d like anything in return, don’t be shy. Let them know that you want to go like Chuck Yeager.
2. Become a Key Influencer or get press credentials. This is much safer and probably your best bet. I’d probably try starting a YouTube channel about all the cool stuff the Airforce does and hope the followers start subscribing. I’d think that + a high ranking officer as fried, and you’d be in the money!

I’d also tell every member of the Airforce, Navy, and Marines, that your dream in life is to go Mach 1. I’ve been amazed at some of the things I’ve gotten to do just by asking politely. But, my requests are usually subsonic or sexual in nature.

Note: To my knowledge It is illegal to exceed Mach 1 above the continental United States. (Nevada may have an exception for the huge test area.) So, if you get to go on one of these rides, make damn sure you you’re on the coast and flying over the ocean. If you fly out of Dallas Love field or something, you’re going to get a subsonic only joyride. If that pilot exceeds the speed of sound above a populated area just because you want to, it will be his last time operating any jet owned by the DOD.

Comment: The Blue Angels are the Navy Flight Demonstration Team.  The Air Force team is called The Thunderbirds.